# Unable to intercept Page Up/Down keys

Tags: c, linux, unix, terminal, posix

I am [here](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/03.rawInputAndOutput.html#the-page-up-and-page-down-keys) on a tutorial to build a text editor.

I'm finding that on my macOS (also tested on a Linux VM on the machine -- and it works properly there), even with raw mode enabled, I'm unable to intercept `Page Up` and `Page Down`, which are sent via `fn-<arrow up>` `fn-<arrow down>`. How can I intercept these correctly?

Here's a simple program that you can use to see this:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct termios orig_termios;

void
disable_raw_mode (void)
{
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &orig_termios);
}

void
enable_raw_mode (void)
{
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &orig_termios);
  atexit(disable_raw_mode);

  struct termios raw = orig_termios;
  raw.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | INPCK | PARMRK | INLCR | IGNCR | ISTRIP | ICRNL | IXON);
  raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
  raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
  raw.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
  raw.c_cflag |= (CS8);


  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}

int
main (void)
{
  enable_raw_mode();
  
  char c;
  while ( read(STDIN_FILENO,  &c, 1) == 1 && c != 'q')
    {
      if (iscntrl(c))
        printf("%d\n", c);
      else
        printf("%d ('%c')\n", c, c);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

I want the final text editor to work on all POSIX-compliant systems that support escape sequences via the terminal.

Note that both `emacs` and `vim` intercept these properly.

Comment: First, verify that the arrow and fn-arrow keys send the expected sequences. I like to use `od` for this sort of thing (preferably GNU `od` since it also supports the `-z` flag). So running `od -tx1`, pressing up-arrow then fn-up-arrow then Enter then Ctrl-D I see this output: `1b  5b  41  1b  5b  35  7e  0a` which is what I would expect. Note that you **do not** need raw mode to handle these sequences; although you'll want raw mode so that special-chars like Ctrl-D are passed through by the tty driver. So modify your program to not enable raw mode and have it echo the chars.

Comment: the provided code seems to work on macos, try running it without buffered input / output like this `gcc main.c  && stdbuf -i 0 -o 0 -e 0 ./a.out`, when pressing up arrow this is output: `0x1b 0x5b 0x41` which seems to agree with @KurtisRader `od -tx1` output, nice work!
oops, forgot to mention I changed the output to this `printf( " 0x%02x", c );`

Comment: one more thing, you may also want to use a better terminal like iterm2, using that terminal emulator pressing fn+up arrow produces this output `stdbuf -i 0 -o 0 -e 0 ./a.out
 0x1b 0x5b 0x35 0x7e` which might be an issue (terminal capturing keys first), pressing fn+up in default terminal just scrolls up, see download here https://iterm2.com/downloads.html

Comment: more on editing osx terminal key strokes here: https://fdiv.net/2007/05/12/keybindings-mac-os-x-104s-terminalapp
And ncurses is a fun read too, https://www.gnu.org/software/guile-ncurses/manual/html_node/Getting-characters-from-the-keyboard.html

Comment: @atl the problem is what you are saying. `fn+<key-up>` scrolls up instead of being caught. What I find interesting is that in macOS `Terminal.app`, `vim` is somehow able to catch this keystroke.

Comment: `emacs` also catches and uses these keystrokes (alongside `Home` and `End`), both in `Terminal.app` and as a standalone GUI.